# camunda external database integration

Tags: camunda

I am doing a POC to integrate camunda with oracle database. It works well with h2 database. To integrate with oracle, I have followed this user guide (https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.17/user-guide/spring-boot-integration/configuration/). My application programmatically creates a datasource and transaction manager so i have no control over it. I tried to create a secondary transaction manager using above user guide and it fails due to two transaction manager bean found.

Is there a way to connect with the programmatically created datasource instead of providing a configuration.